# When is it most beneficial to use a virtual function instead of overriding and vice versa in C++

Tags: c++, overriding

I am fairly new to C++ and am curious when is it most beneficial time to use a virtual function instead of just using overriding and vice versa in C++?

Comment: If you really want your head to explode, read up on virtual base classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function as virtual in a base class, you are indicating to the compiler that you want the function in a derived class to run even though you are using a reference to the base class. This causes a run-time decision.

If the base class function is not virtual, then which function runs depends on the reference. This is a compile-time decision.

Virtual functions are used to implement polymorphism in an object-oriented design. More often than not, failing to mark a function in a base class as virtual, when there is a same-named function in a derived class, is a bug. That's why most compilers will flag this as a warning.